# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola compañeros tengo un gran problema con el insertar en la DB y no encuentro el error necesito ayuda para resolverlo y aprender de el, me muestra que el error esta en el or die pero no encuentro nada en el.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $codigo = mt_rand (1,9999999999);
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];





$añadir = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO colaborador(`id-colaborador`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `correo`, `telefono`, `codigo`, `usuario`, `contraseña`)
 VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$codigo', '$usuario', '$password')")
 or die ($conexion."Problemas en el insert de colaboradores");

echo ' <script language="javascript"> alert("Colaborador registrado con éxito");</script> ';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba modificando tu consulta `INSERT` de este modo:

- Quita el `or die` del método `mysqli_query()` dejando solo la variable de `$conexion` y la query sql

Código

```
$añadir = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO colaborador(`id-colaborador`, 
                                 `nombre`, `apellido`, `correo`, `telefono`, 
                                 `codigo`, `usuario`, `contraseña`)
                                 VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', 
                                 '$telefono', '$codigo', '$usuario', 
                                 '$password')");
```

Posterior para verificar si la conexión se llevó a cabo hacemos esto:

- Verifica el estado de la query indicando con `!` que si no se llevó a cabo imprima un mensaje y en caso contrario imprima otro

Código

```
if(!$añadir) {
    echo ' <script language="javascript"> alert("Colaborador no registrado con éxito");</script> ';
} else {
    echo ' <script language="javascript"> alert("Colaborador registrado con éxito");</script> ';
}
```

Finalmente considera:

- Si el `id` es `PK` y `AUTO_INCREMENT` no necesitas invocar a la columna y tampoco asignar un valor `NULL`
- Evita el uso de caracteres especiales para nombrar a tus columnas tales como:

  - acentos
  - letra `ñ`
  - etc.

Comment: Gracias amigo funciono el error ya se fue, pero.. me dice Colaborador no registrado con éxito. ¿ya que hago que es lo que impide el insertar?

Comment: Hice una modificación @JuanCamiloRinconGil prueba y avisame

Comment: el id de tu tabvla es PK y auto_increment @JuanCamiloRinconGil ?

Comment: Si señor, pero ya me funciono tuve un pequeño problema y fue con la Ñ en el campo contraseña en la DB.